# How to serve an image from google cloud storage using python flask

Tags: python, image, google-app-engine, flask, google-cloud-storage

I'm currently working on a project running flask on the Appengine standard environment, and I'm attempting to serve an image that has been uploaded onto Google Cloud Storage on my project's default Appengine storage bucket.

This is the routing code I currently have:

```
# main.py

from google.appengine.api import images
from flask import Flask, send_file

app = Flask(__name__)

...

@app.route("/sample_route")
def sample_handler():
    myphoto = images.Image(filename="/gs/myappname.appspot.com/mysamplefolder/photo.jpg")
    return send_file(myphoto)
...
```

However, I am getting an `AttributeError: 'Image' object has no attribute 'read'` error.

The question is, how do I serve an image sourced from google cloud storage using an arbitrary route using python and flask?

EDIT:

I am actually trying to serve an image that I have uploaded to the default Cloud Storage Bucket in my app engine project.

I've also tried to serve the image using the following code without success:

```
# main.py

from google.appengine.api import images
from flask import Flask, send_file

app = Flask(__name__)

...

@app.route("/sample_route")
def sample_handler():
    import cloudstorage as gcs
    gcs_file = gcs.open("/mybucketname/mysamplefolder/photo.jpg")
    img = gcs_file.read()
    gcs_file.close()

    return send_file(img, mimetype='image/jpeg')
...
```

Comment: Are you trying to send it as bytes?

Comment: Hi. What I want to do is, when the user loads the url in his browser or if the url is included in a page, the browser should display the image.

Comment: I have photos in google cloud storage that I want the user to be able to load. The image from `url_to_image` should load when the user goes to `http://example.com/sample_route`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've used the [`GoogleAppEngineCloudStorageClient`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/googlecloudstorageclient/setting-up-cloud-storage#downloading_the_client_library) Python library and loaded images with code similar to the following example:

```
from google.appengine.api import app_identity
import cloudstorage
from flask import Flask, send_file
import io, os

app = Flask(__name__)

# ...

@app.route('/imagetest')
def test_image():

  # Use BUCKET_NAME or the project default bucket.
  BUCKET_NAME = '/' + os.environ.get('MY_BUCKET_NAME',
                                     app_identity.get_default_gcs_bucket_name())
  filename = 'mytestimage.jpg'
  file = os.path.join(BUCKET_NAME, filename)

  gcs_file = cloudstorage.open(file)
  contents = gcs_file.read()
  gcs_file.close()

  return send_file(io.BytesIO(contents),
                   mimetype='image/jpeg')
```

Comment: Thanks, the image is now served successfully. It looks like I just have to serve the image as bytes. `return send_file(io.BytesIO(contents),
                   mimetype='image/jpeg')`

Answer (score 6):

Using [google-cloud-storage==1.6.0](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/google-cloud-storage/1.6.0)

```
from flask import current_app as app, send_file, abort
from google.cloud import storage
import tempfile

@app.route('/blobproxy/<filename>', methods=['GET'])
def get(filename):
    if filename:
        client = storage.Client()
        bucket = client.get_bucket('yourbucketname')
        blob = bucket.blob(filename)
        with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as temp:
            blob.download_to_filename(temp.name)
            return send_file(temp.name, attachment_filename=filename)
    else:
        abort(400)
```

I recommend looking at [the docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/quickstart/#variable-rules) for the `path` or `string` converters for your route, and `NamedTemporaryFile` defaults to `delete=True` so no residue.
`flask` also figures out the `mimetype` if you give it a file name, as is the case here.

Comment: Finally, an answer that worked for me. Can't thank you enough :)

Answer (score 3):

Are you trying to accomplish something like this:

```
@app.route("/sample_route")
def sample_handler():
    import urllib2
    import StringIO

    request = urllib2.Request("{image url}")

    img = StringIO.StringIO(urllib2.urlopen(request).read())
    return send_file(img, mimetype='image/jpeg') # display in browser
```

or

```
    return send_file(img) # download file
```

The image url is needed, not a relative path.  You could just do a redirect to the image url, but they would get a 301.

Comment: The image url I'm trying to load is actually from the default Google Cloud Storage bucket in my app, and the images may not necessarily be publicly accessible.

Although I am attempting this with different external image urls, however I am getting a `The image "myproject.appspot.com/sample" cannot be displayed because it contains errors` message. I've also tried switching the mimetype from `image/jpeg` to `image/png`, with the same error.

Comment: When you uploaded the image, did you set `options={'x-goog-acl': 'public-read',...}`?  Did you try to enter that URL directly in your browser?  If they aren't public, you'll need to use `cloudstorage.open()` to get them.

Comment: I've tried your solution again, and it works.  Using a different browser allowed the image to load successfully.  This isn't the exact solution I'm looking for, but I'll be able to use it if I decide to serve images from other locations. Thanks.